# Why does the {magrittr}/{dplyr} pipe not work with certain functions (e.g. `mget`)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have seen this occur in a couple of instances but as it is an easy fix, I'd never asked:

- Sometimes the {magrittr}/{dplyr} pipe works differently than if you explicitly supply the input to the RHS function.
- Is this something to do with environments? See the below example where we can fix by either:

  - Not using the pipe
  - Supplying the environment explicitly (which we shouldn't have to do)

```
library(dplyr)
iris_test_1 <- iris
iris_test_2 <- iris
iris_test_3 <- iris
iris_test_4 <- iris

# Find objects starting with certain letters in global
# environment (this relies on you having a clean global
# environment)

# Works
ge_datasets <- ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") 

mget(ge_datasets) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  as_tibble()

# Doesn't work
ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") %>% 
  mget() %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  as_tibble()

# Works
ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") %>% 
  mget(.GlobalEnv) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `parent.frame`.  By default, it uses `as.environment(-1)` i.e.

> The default of -1 indicates the current environment of the call to get.

```
ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") %>%
      mget(envir = parent.frame())
```

The `%>%` creates an environment and as `mget` by default only checks in the current environment (as `inherits = FALSE` by default - it is TRUE in `get` though), it couldn't find the object.  An option would be to specify `inherits = TRUE`

```
ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") %>%
   mget(inherits = TRUE)
```

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't entirely clear - the question I had was _why_ do we need to supply an environment? Note that in the original '#works' bit, we didn't supply one. Is that because the pipe is doing things in a separate environment? And so the `mget` default environment doesn't work as it would without a pipe?

Comment: @AndrewLittle The pipe does create a environment and thus causing `mget` to fail because by default `inherits = FALSE` in `mget` whereas it is `TRUE` with `get`.  i.e. it can work with `ls(pattern = "^iris_test_") %>% mget(inherits = TRUE)`

Comment: @AndrewLittle you can check the source code of `%>%`

Comment: Makes perfect sense. If you edit your answer to be the above two comments I’ll mark as answer. Thanks :)